# How to add shortcuts ("templates") to eclipse properties through my plugin?

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I'm developing a plugin for visualization of objects by calling `Doo.dle(Object o)`.
Now I'd like to automatically define a shortcut like `sysout` for `System.out.println()`, e.g. `doodle`.

I already know how to do it by hand:

`Window` > `Preferences` > `Java` > `Editor` > `Templates`

Is there an extension point or something similar to do this automatically with my plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it on my own:

I had to define a `javaCompletionProposalComputer` extension and implement an `ICompletionProposal`.

It's not exactly what I intended, but it's working too.

**Update:**

I finally found it out:

The key is to define an extension for `org.eclipse.ui.editors.templates`. Patterns etc. can be cheated off predifined templates in eclipse properties (see question).